# wordpress custom post type returns 404

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

I have created a custom post type like this,

```
add_action( 'init', 'used_cars_cpt' );
```

function used_cars_cpt() {

```
register_post_type('used-cars', [
    'labels' => [
        'name' => 'Used Cars',
        'singular_name' => 'Used Car',
    ],
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'cars'),
    'description' => '',
    'public' => true,
    'menu_position' => 20,
    'supports' => ['custom-fields']
]);
```

}

I can create post using this post type, but when I try to view the post I get a 404, the only time I can view it, is when I use plain permalinks but I would like to use the `/cars/some-kind-of-post-title`. Can anyone point into the direction as to why my post type on pretty permalinks is 404ing?

I have tried flushing the permalinks.

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
/*
* Creating a function to create our CPT
*/

function custom_post_type() {

// Set UI labels for Custom Post Type
    $labels = array(
        'name'                => 'Used Cars',
        'singular_name'       => 'Used Cars',
        'menu_name'           => 'Used Cars',
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Used Cars', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'All Used Cars', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'view_item'           => __( 'View Used Cars', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Used Cars', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Used Cars', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Update Used Cars', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Search Used Cars', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'not_found'           => __( 'Not Found', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'twentythirteen' ),
    );

// Set other options for Custom Post Type

    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'Used Cars', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'description'         => __( 'Used Cars desc', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        // Features this CPT supports in Post Editor
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', ),
        /* A hierarchical CPT is like Pages and can have
        * Parent and child items. A non-hierarchical CPT
        * is like Posts.
        */ 
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'page',
    );

    // Registering your Custom Post Type
    register_post_type( 'cars', $args );

}

/* Hook into the 'init' action so that the function
* Containing our post type registration is not 
* unnecessarily executed. 
*/

add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type', 0 );
```

you must update permalink after change code.

more info at [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)

Answer (score 0):

```
Please use this:

    <?php

function cars() {
  register_post_type('cars',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __('Cars', 'domain_name'),
        'singular_name' => __('Car', 'domain_name'),
        'all_items' => __('All Cars CPTs', 'domain_name'),
        'add_new' => __('Add New Car', 'domain_name'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Car', 'domain_name'),
        'edit' => __('Edit', 'domain_name'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Car', 'domain_name'),
        'new_item' => __('New Car', 'domain_name'),
        'view_item' => __('View Car', 'domain_name'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Car', 'domain_name'),
        'not_found' =>  __('No Car found. Add some and they\'ll appear here!', 'domain_name'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Deleted Cars will appear here.', 'domain_name'),
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
      ),

      'description' => __('cars', 'domain_name'),
      'public' => true,
      'publicly_queryable' => true,
      'exclude_from_search' => false,
      'show_ui' => true,
      'query_var' => true,
      'menu_position' => 8,
      'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-media-default',
      'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'cars',
        'with_front' => false 
      ),

      'has_archive' => 'cars',
      'capability_type' => 'post',
      'hierarchical' => false,
      'supports' => array(
        'title',
        'editor',
        'author',
        'page-attributes',
        'thumbnail',
        'excerpt',
        'trackbacks',
        'custom-fields',
        'comments',
        'revisions',
        'sticky'
      )
    )
  );

  register_taxonomy_for_object_type('cars-category', 'cars');
  register_taxonomy_for_object_type('cars-tag', 'cars');
}

add_action('init', 'cars');

register_taxonomy( 'cars-category', 
  array('cars'),
  array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => array(
      'name' => __('Categories', 'domain_name'),
      'singular_name' => __('Category', 'domain_name'),
      'search_items' =>  __('Search Categories', 'domain_name'),
      'all_items' => __('All Categories', 'domain_name'),
      'parent_item' => __('Parent Category', 'domain_name'),
      'parent_item_colon' => __('Parent Category:', 'domain_name'),
      'edit_item' => __('Edit Category', 'domain_name'),
      'update_item' => __('Update Category', 'domain_name'),
      'add_new_item' => __('Add New Category', 'domain_name'),
      'new_item_name' => __('New Category Name', 'domain_name')
    ),

    'show_admin_column' => true, 
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'cars-categories' ),
  )
);

register_taxonomy('cars-tag', 
  array('cars'),
  array(
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'labels' => array(
      'name' => __('Tags', 'domain_name'),
      'singular_name' => __('Tag', 'domain_name'),
      'search_items' =>  __('Search Tags', 'domain_name'),
      'all_items' => __('All Tags', 'domain_name'),
      'parent_item' => __('Parent Tag', 'domain_name'),
      'parent_item_colon' => __('Parent Tag:', 'domain_name'),
      'edit_item' => __('Edit Tag', 'domain_name'),
      'update_item' => __('Update Tag', 'domain_name'),
      'add_new_item' => __('Add New Tag', 'domain_name'),
      'new_item_name' => __('New Tag Name', 'domain_name')
    ),

    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
  )
);

?>
```

Don't forget to save permalinks again.

Answer (score 0):

This will Works. And Also try by Changing Permalink from Settings

```
    function used_cars_cpt() {

    $args = array(
        'labels' => [
        'name' => 'Used Cars',
        'singular_name' => 'Used Car',
    ],
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'cars'),
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'show_in_menu'       => true,
    'query_var'          => true,
    'description' => '',
    'public' => true,
    'capability_type'    => 'post',
    'menu_position' => 20,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),
    );

    register_post_type( 'used-cars', $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'used_cars_cpt' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just go to Settings -> Permalinks
Select Post name option if its not already set, if its already set to this option thus hit the save button in both cases.
It will update your htaccess again and permalinks will work.